# Teachings that Inspire Practice

Tags: teaching, right-effort

Where, on the internet, are motivational ebooks, blog entries or whatever that have concise motivating advice, excerpts, quotes and koans  that might motivate one to practice?

Comment: Here's an easy one - you only think you have time.

Comment: Cold Mountain is a great collection of such poems.
The ultimate motivation: look at your cemetary ground.

Answer (score 4):

Read the nice anecdotes of [Ajaan Fuang](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/thai/fuang/itself.html). A small selection below.

> § A woman came to Wat Dhammasathit to observe the precepts and
>   meditate for a week, but by the end of the second day she told Ajaan
>   Fuang that she had to return home, because she was afraid her family
>   couldn't get along without her. He taught her to cut through her
>   worries by saying, "When you come here, tell yourself that you've
>   died. One way or another, your family will have to learn to fend for
>   themselves."
>
> § "We keep disagreeable people around the monastery as a way of
>   testing to see if our defilements really are all gone."
>
> § "Don't make a journal of your meditation experiences. If you do,
>   you'll start meditating in order to have this or that thing happen, so
>   that you can write it down in your journal. And as a result, you'll
>   end up with nothing but the things you've fabricated."
>
> § "When the meditation goes well, don't get excited. When it doesn't
>   go well, don't get depressed. Simply be observant to see why it's
>   good, why it's bad. If you can be observant like this, it won't be
>   long before your meditation becomes a skill."
>
> § A student came to complain to Ajaan Fuang that she had been
>   meditating for years, and still hadn't gotten anything out of it. His
>   immediate response: "You don't meditate to 'get' anything. You
>   meditate to let go."
>
> § "You should watch visions (in meditation) the same way you watch TV:
>   Just watch it, without getting pulled inside the tube."